# Difference between "SELECT column1 FROM table1" & "SELECT ALL column1 FROM table1"

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the difference between the following two queries? I find no difference between them.

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1

SELECT ALL column1 FROM table1
```

Comment: `SELECT ALL` is a no-op.  The `ALL` is ignored and simply not used in practice.

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) says:

> The ALL and DISTINCT modifiers specify whether duplicate rows should be returned. ALL (the default) specifies that all matching rows should be returned, including duplicates.

This means there is no difference between those two queries. if `SELECT column1 FROM table1` is executed, the engine automatically add `ALL` next to the `SELECT` keyword and the query becomes `SELECT ALL column1 FROM table1`.